# Spell Correction For Numbers using Deep Learning

Tags: python, lstm

I am New to Deep Learning(I understand the basics).I Wanted to know If Spell Correction of "numbers" is possible Using LSTM's .
For example,If I typed 289\78.
It should show 295\78.Provided that 295\78 is present in my training set.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In theory: Yes.

In practice: Don't use Deep Learning for this.

Take `289/78` as a string and run [Fuzzy String Matching](http://chairnerd.seatgeek.com/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/) over the dataset. Output the sample which shows the highest similarity to your input.